# Отключение фильтра на первой странице

Tags: java, url, servlet, filter, аутентификация

Я сделал фильтр аутентификации, чтобы нельзя было по прямой ссылке получать права определенных пользователей.

Код фильтра:

```
import ProjectHotel.Path;
import jakarta.servlet.*;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.*;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import java.io.IOException;

@WebFilter(filterName = "AuthFilter")
public class AuthFilter implements Filter {
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        final HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        final HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);

        String uri = req.getRequestURI();

        String email = (String)session.getAttribute("email");

        if (email==null && (uri.contains("/user") || uri.contains("/manager") || uri.contains("/admin"))) {
            res.sendRedirect(Path.ERROR_PAGE);
        }
        else {
            chain.doFilter(request,response);
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

И добавил этот фильтр в `web.xml`

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>AuthFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>ProjectHotel.Controller.Filters.AuthFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>AuthFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>something here</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Как мне указать `<url-pattern>`, чтобы фильтр не срабатывал на стартовой странице. Ибо поскольку я еще не зашел в аккаунт - сессии нет, из-за чего ловлю исключение.

Comment: `url-pattern` ставится на адреса, на которые фильтр срабатывает.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете Servlet 3.0 и [аннотацию `@WebFilter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebFilter.html), то `web.xml` не нужен, и описывать адреса, на которые парится фильтр можно с помощью атрибута `urlPatterns`:

> ```
> public abstract String[] urlPatterns
> ```
>
> Шаблоны URL, к которым применяется фильтр
>
> По умолчанию:{}

Можно поставить проверку, например

```
String uri = req.getRequestURI();
if (uri.equals("/")) {chain.doFilter(req, res); return;}
```